# Memory leak when using a TextBox within an ItemsControl

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I've been struggling to find the reason for the memory leak. I have the following XAML:

```
                <ItemsControl Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" x:Name="FieldsView" Background="Transparent">
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid Margin="0 5">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition MaxWidth="300" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <StackPanel Grid.Column="1">
                                <Grid>
                                    <TextBox Tag="firstname" Text="" /> 
                                </Grid>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ItemsControl>
```

I've removed all the bindings to simplify the XAML. I was commenting stuff out to get to the core leak.

According to dotMemory here is the leak analysis

[image]

I know its the TextBox because if I comment it out the leak dissappears. I'm using .NET framework 4.7.2.

I saw a post about the undo function so I've styled my TextBox to remove it but that did not fix it.

```
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
    <Setter Property="IsUndoEnabled" Value="False"/>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource TextBox.Background}" />
    <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="60" />
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0" />
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="22pt"/>
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Segoe UI Light" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TextBoxBase}">
                <Border x:Name="border" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                    <ScrollViewer x:Name="PART_ContentHost" Focusable="False" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" />
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#FF7EB4EA" />
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

The ItemsControl is populated using an ObservableCollection

```
private ObservableCollection<RegistrationFieldViewModel> _model;
_model = new ObservableCollection<RegistrationFieldViewModel>(visitorTypeSettingInfo.Fields.Select(a => new RegistrationFieldViewModel
        {
            Key = a.Key,
            Mandatory = a.Mandatory,
            UseAsLookup = a.UseAsLookup,
            Type = a.Type
        }).ToList());
        FieldsView.ItemsSource = _model;
```

and RegistrationFieldViewModel implements INotifyPropertyChanged

Comment: How do you figure that this a leak?

Comment: Because a reference to my UserControl is being kept each time I do a workflow in my application. I take a snapshot using dotMemory, do a workflow then do another snapshot then compare the two. I'm also forcing a GC collection after each workflow.

Comment: Before focusing too much on the `TextBox`, have you tried using other controls (say, `Label` or `TextBlock`) and see how they behave? Also, were you profiling with or without the debugger connected? (The VS debugger is known for holding on to references for much longer than it needs to)

Comment: OK I think you are right...must be something to do with running the debugger. Wasted way too much time on this and was pulling my hair out. Thanks.

Comment: It's a rite of passage for every dev. Learning the painful way to not trust any memory/perf profile  when the debugger is on.

Comment: "F-Reachable Queue" probably means the control is on the finalizer queue, that does not necessarily indicate a problem as they should be cleaned up and removed from the queue with time. If they do not you might have a problem with the finalizer thread being hung for some reason.

Comment: Thank you I have learned quite a few things. It turns out I didn't have a memory leak. Its a misunderstanding of the tools and process.